# Difference Between php_admin_value[memory_limit] and php.ini memory_limit

Tags: php, nginx, debian

I have Nginx + php-fpm + Mysql. With the php memory settings, I always set this in php.ini like this:

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

Now, I bumped into another similar looking setting in `pool.d/www.conf` file like this:

```
;php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 32M
```

My questions:

**Although the doc says what that does, I couldnt read anywhere on what's the difference between memory_limit setting in `php.ini` and the `php_admin_value[memory_limit]` in `www.conf`?**

**Do I need to set both or setting both makes it redundant**?

**Under what scenario do I need to specify the limit in `php_admin_value[memory_limit]` instead of adding it to `memory_limit` in `php.ini`?**

Can someone clear my confusion please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference. There are different ways to set the same PHP configuration parameter.
It's useful - for example - if you have a generic php.ini which gets loaded in all PHP-FPM pools, but in one of them you want to override a certain value - like `memory_limit`

See http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Comment: Thanks. So just having it in php.ini should be good enough then.

Comment: Good enough. right.

Answer (score 7):

One difference between `memory_limit = 256M` in php.ini and `php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 32M` in pool.d/www.conf is that you can use `ini_set('memory_limit','512M')` to override the setting in php.ini but you can't override values set with `php_admin_value`.

Use `php_value[memory_limit] = 32M` if you want to allow it to be overridden. (`php_value` vs `php_admin_value`)